# Ассемблер. Заменить заданную подстроку на другую заданную подстроку

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Не заменяется последняя из подстрок, если заменяемая подстрока короче. Например, при вводе строки "stack stack stack", если попробовать заменить подстроку "ta" на "ololo", выведет: "sololock sololock stack".

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1 db "Input string:", 0dh, 0ah, '$' 
msg2 db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter the substring you want to delete:", 0dh, 0ah, '$'
msg3 db 0dh, 0ah, "Result: $" 
msg4 db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter new substring: $"
string db 202 dup("$")
sbstrToRemove db 202 dup("$")
sbstrToInsert db 202 dup("$")
capacity EQU 200
flag dw 0

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax 

mov ah, capacity     
mov string[0], ah    ;first byte - max srting size
mov sbstrToRemove[0], ah 
mov sbstrToInsert[0], ah     

lea dx, msg1
call puts
lea dx, string
call gets

lea dx, msg2
call puts
lea dx, sbstrToRemove
call gets            

lea dx, msg4
call puts
lea dx, sbstrToInsert
call gets

xor cx, cx
mov cl, string[1]
sub cl, sbstrToRemove[1]
jb End
inc cl
cld

lea si, string[2]
lea di, sbstrToRemove[2]

call ReplaceSubstring

End:   
lea dx, msg3
call puts
lea dx, string[2]
call puts

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

ret
endp main  


ReplaceSubstring proc
Cycle:
mov flag, 1
push si
push di
push cx

mov bx, si

xor cx, cx
mov cl, sbstrToRemove[1]

repe cmpsb
je FOUND
jne NOT_FOUND

FOUND:
call DeleteSubstring   
mov ax, bx
call InsertSubstring
mov flag, 0
;mov dl, sbstrToInsert[1]
;mov flag, dx
NOT_FOUND:
pop cx
pop di
pop si
add si, flag

Loop Cycle

ret
endp ReplaceSubstring  

DeleteSubstring proc
push si
push di
mov cl, string[1]
mov di, bx

repe movsb

pop di
pop si

ret                
endp DeleteSubstring

InsertSubstring proc
lea cx, string[2]   ; string 1st symbol address
add cl, string[1]   ; add string length to get to next symbol after the last
mov si, cx          ; last symbol as a source 
dec si              ; at the last symbol
mov bx, si          ; save last symbol in bx
add bl, sbstrToInsert[1] ; now there is the last symbol of new string in bx
mov di, bx          ; new last symbol is reciever
;inc bx             

mov dx, ax          ; ax is a place to insert
sub cx, dx          ; after last symbol -= place to insert
std                 ; moving backward
repe movsb

lea si, sbstrToInsert[2] ; source is sbstr 1st symbol
mov di, ax          ; reciever is a place to insert
xor cx, cx          ; set cx to zero
mov cl, sbstrToInsert[1] ; sbstr length to cx
cld                 ; moving forward
repe movsb            

ret
endp InsertSubstring                

; I/O procedures

gets proc   
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
ret
endp gets

puts proc
mov ah, 9 
int 21h
ret
endp puts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено: не обновлял реальную длину строк после замены подстроки. Вот исправленная часть кода:

```
FOUND:
call DeleteSubstring
mov ax, bx
call InsertSubstring
mov dl, sbstrToInsert[1] ; эти две строки
add string[1], dl        ; нужно вставить
mov flag, dx
```